# Acrobat X Forms: Trying to populate text box with value from radio button

Tags: java, adobe, acrobat

I am a complete novice with java. Searching for examples and/or meaningful instructions is non-productive. I do fairly well with Excel expressions but this apparently does not cross over.

Trying to automate an invoice within a pdf using Acrobat X (PC version, not cloud). I have a group of radio buttons with different numeric values. User can choose only one. I want the value in the button to appear in a separate text field.

The end product will have several groups as described above with the text fields then used in a simple sum equation to generate a combined total.

Quite frankly I have not "tried" anything. Searched for examples or instructions to no avail. I don't even know of the actions should originate from the radio buttons or the text field.

Don't know if the actions belong in the Simplified Field Notation box or in the Custom Calculation Script.

I've been digging through the 700 page "manual" for the use of java in Acrobat forms and am just plain stumped.

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing Java with JavaScript. They are two completely different and incompatible languages. Try searching for JavaScript and Adobe Forms.